# Vimeo Api - Can't fire playProgress event using Froogaloop

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api, froogaloop

Can anyone help me? Here is the JSFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/uupd4/ ).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video_src = '7100569';
    var $video_wrapper = $('body');    
    var $video = $('iframe');

    $video_vimeo = $f($video[0]);
    $video_vimeo.addEvent('ready', vimeo_ready);

    function vimeo_ready(){
        console.log('ready');
        $video_vimeo.addEvent('playProgress', onProgress);
    }

    function onProgress(data){
        console.log('onProgress');
    }
});
```

I did what the documentation says to add playProgress event only when the ready event is triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and after a long time looking at every detail of the vimeo example:

http://player.vimeo.com/playground

I found a solution for this, just send as parameter to the url vimeo name "player_id", ie the id of your iframe.

http://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?player_id=player_1